# RPM failed dependency that's already installed

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, rpm

We have an old dev server for Centos 6 I want to update Openssl to a modified version 1.0.2k (we have got a C8 server to replace it, but trying to update the old one in the interim).

I have built the RPM from a SRPM, and trying to install. Example

```
rpm -Uv openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64.rpm  openssl-1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64.rpm openssl-devel-1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

However, it comes up with the error:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
    openssl-devel = 1.0.1e-58.el6_10 is needed by (installed) openssl-static-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64
```

Yet if I go to look at Openssl-dev that's installed, I get

```
Installed Packages
Name        : openssl-devel
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 58.el6_10
Size        : 2.2 M
Repo        : installed
From repo   : updates

Available Packages
Name        : openssl-devel
Arch        : i686
Version     : 1.0.1e
Release     : 58.el6_10
Size        : 1.2 M
Repo        : updates

rpmquery openssl-devel
openssl-devel-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64
```

So it seems to imply I have the correct version installed (for it to resolve), however I also note in the 'available packages' section, it doesn't list the x86_64 package (normally I would expect it to show i686 and x86_64), and wondering if something is astray there.

If I look at arch output it shows

```
x86_64
```

And all other installed packages are x86_64

My yum.conf and /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo all look correct with no modifications.

An rpm query shows

```
rpm -qpR openssl-libs-1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
/sbin/ldconfig  
/sbin/ldconfig  
ca-certificates >= 2008-5
config(openssl-libs) = 1:1.0.2k-21.el6
libc.so.6()(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit)  
libcom_err.so.2()(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)  
libdl.so.2()(64bit)  
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libgssapi_krb5.so.2()(64bit)  
libk5crypto.so.3()(64bit)  
libk5crypto.so.3(k5crypto_3_MIT)(64bit)  
libkrb5.so.3()(64bit)  
libkrb5.so.3(krb5_3_MIT)(64bit)  
libssl.so.10()(64bit)  
libz.so.1()(64bit)  
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(VersionedDependencies) <= 3.0.3-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)  
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1

rpm -qpR openssl-1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64.rpm
/bin/bash  
/bin/sh  
coreutils  
libc.so.6()(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)  
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit)  
libcom_err.so.2()(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10()(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.1_EC)(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit)  
libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit)  
libdl.so.2()(64bit)  
libgssapi_krb5.so.2()(64bit)  
libk5crypto.so.3()(64bit)  
libkrb5.so.3()(64bit)  
libssl.so.10()(64bit)  
libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit)  
libz.so.1()(64bit)  
make  
openssl-libs(x86-64) = 1:1.0.2k-21.el6
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)  
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
```

Any ideas why the rpm upgrade fails with the missing dependency ?

Comment: if I'm reading the error messages correctly, you are trying to update (among others) openssl-devel from 1.0.1e to 1.0.2k, but the 1.0.1e version is required by the package ```openssl-static-1.0.1e-58.el6_10.x86_64``` (read carefully, that is not one of the packages you are trying to update!)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where that requirement came from though (I updated the rpm query). However I think it seems to work if I include openssl-1.0.2k-21.el6.src.rpm and openssl-static-1.0.2k-21.el6.x86_64.rpm with the update your comment led me down the right path.